# Java - SwingWorker - problem

Tags: java, user-interface, swingworker, callable

I am developing a Java Desktop Application. This app executes the same task `public class MyTask implements Callable<MyObject> {` in multiple thread simultaneously.

Now, when a user clicks on a "start" button, I have created a `SwingWorker myWorker` and have executed it.

Now, this `myWorker` creates multiple instances of `MyTask` and submits them to an `ExecutorService`.

Each `MyTask` instance has a loop and generates an intermediate result at every iteration. Now, I want to collect these intermediate results from each `MyTask` instances as soon as they are generated. Then after collecting these intermediate results from every `MyTask` instance, I want to publish it through `SwingWorker.publish(MyObject)` so that the progress is shown on the EDT.

**Q1.** How can I implement this? Should I make `MyTask` subclass of `SwingWorker` instead of `Callable` to get intermediate results also, because I think that `Callable` only returns final result.

**Q2.** If the answer of Q1. is yes, then can you give me a small example to show how can I get those intermediate results and aggregate them and then publish them from main `SwingWorker`?

**Q3.** If I can't use `SwingWorker` in this situation, then how can I implement this?

Comment: When you collect the intermediate results from each task, do you want them all to be from the same iteration? I.e. collect all iteration 1 results, then iteration 2 results?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ExecutorCompletionService<T>](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). It's an Executor that supplies a `take` method to retrieve the result of any completed task.

**Update:**

Extending `SwingWorker` will not do what you want as it is specifically intended for offloading work from the EDT to a background thread. You can't use it to offload work from a background thread to other background threads. Calls to `SwingWorker.publish` result in the equivalent of a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. There is no mechanism I am aware of for doing the same thing from a background thread to a background thread.  Your best bet is to create your `MyTask` with a reference to a `Queue` and have your `SwingWorker.doInBackground` poll the queue for intermediate results.

Comment: I want to create several `SwingWorker` from one `SwingWorker mainWorker`. This `mainWorker` is initiated by EDT. The reason for creating several workers from the main worker is that I want to gather intermediate results of all those workers in the `mainWorker` and then publish those intermediate results via. `publish(...)` method of `mainWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

**A1+A2**. 
Yatendra, is it necessary that your Main `SwingWorker` must be the only one that passes interim results to the `EDT`? If your tasks were also `SwingWorker` instances, the Main Worker could delegate the responsability of sending interim results back to the `EDT` to them and just take care of the `TaskWorkers` life-cycle.

```
package threading;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

class MainSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private List<TaskWorker> tasks;

    public MainSwingWorker() {
        tasks = new LinkedList<TaskWorker>();
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) 
            tasks.add(new TaskWorker(i));
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Test.log("Building tasks.");                    
        for(TaskWorker task : tasks) 
            launch(task);
        Test.log("Waiting 5 secs.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        Test.log("Cancelling tasks");

        for(TaskWorker task : tasks ) 
            task.cancel(true);

        return null;
    }

    private void launch(final TaskWorker task) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test.log("Launching task worker.");
                task.execute();
            }
        });     
    }
}

class TaskWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    private int id;

    public TaskWorker(int wid) {
        id = wid;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {     
        System.out.format("[%s] Starting worker %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), id );
        while( !isCancelled() ) {
            // ***************************
            // your task process code here
            // ***************************
            publish(String.format("A dummy interim result #%s", id));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }       
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<String> results) {
        // it's pretty obvious, that once this method gets called you can safely 
        // call the Swing API from EDT among with the interim results
        for(String result : results )
            Test.log(result);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void log(String msg) {
        System.out.format("[%s] %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        log("Init.");
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log("Starting main worker.");
                MainSwingWorker worker = new MainSwingWorker();
                worker.execute();                           
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        log("Finished.");
    }
}
```

Keep mind that this is just a test, I know that there are a few ugly `Thread.sleep(long)` calls.

```
[main] Init.
[AWT-EventQueue-0] Starting main worker.
[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1] Building tasks.
[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1] Waiting 5 secs.
[AWT-EventQueue-0] Launching task worker.
[AWT-EventQueue-0] Launching task worker.
[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-2] Starting worker 0
[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-3] Starting worker 1
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #1
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #0
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #0
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #1
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #1
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #0
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #0
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #1
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #0
[AWT-EventQueue-0] A dummy interim result #1
[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1] Cancelling tasks
[main] Finished.
```

**A3**
But if having another `ExecutorService` to schedule your task execution is a requirement in your project, I would implement a similar publish-process mechanism to perform communication between your Main Swing Worker Thread and that Task Thread. Although it seems to be repetitive, You may use a `java.concurrent.ConcurrentQueue` to store interim results as they become available?

PS: I just noticed a few days ago, but there is an annoying bug around SwingWorkers that [prevents its ExecutorService from caching unused threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102517/is-this-swingworker-not-reusing-threads-in-threadpoolexecutor).

Answer (score -1):

A SwingWorker is also a Future. As such it has the get() method which can be used inside the done() method to get the result of doInBackground() when that method finishes.

Thus the construct becomes somewhat like:

```
SwingWorker<T,P> sw=new SwingWorker<T,P>() {

  @Override
  public T doInBackground() throws Exception {
    T result;
    // do stuff here
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void done() {
    try {
      T result=get();
      // do stuff with result.
    }
    catch(ExecutionException e) {
      Exception fromDoInBackground= (Exception) e.getCause();
      // handle exception thrown from doInBackground()
    }
    catch(InterruptedException i) {
      // handle the case in which a SwingWorker was cancelled. typically: do nothing.
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @user I request you to first read the question carefully before answering... I know how to use `SwingWorker` already. :)