# Is this SwingWorker not reusing Threads in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

As part of my Final Year Project I've developed a desktop application, which fits in the category of the "graphical IDE" if such a thing exists. I've implemented a little subset of [Jessy James Garrett Visual Vocabulary for Information Architecture and Interaction Design](http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/), so the user can draw a diagram (a directed graph in other words) representing the user's experience in a webapp, assign HTML templates to pages and write some code to a connector/transition that will be executed, once the application is compiled and the user clicks the corresponding hyperlink.

(I can't post more than one hyperlink, but I'm referring to pages and connectors like the Elements of User Experience described in JJG's Visual Vocabulary)

So I'm using a different SwingWorkers to generate a set of C++ source files in which the diagram gets translated into. Looking at the logs, I see that my app is always creating new threads, instead of reusing them.

```
15:29:55.750 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-26] DEBUG i.v.a.ui.worker.ConnectorGenerator - Building source code for transition: connector_29
15:29:55.750 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-26] DEBUG i.v.a.ui.worker.ConnectorGenerator - Project retrieved: sasdasdasd
15:29:55.750 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-26] INFO  i.v.a.webapp.htcpp.CTransition - Generated C:\Workspaces\PFC\aedifico-ui\sasdasdasd\connector_29_action.h...
15:29:55.750 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-26] INFO  i.v.a.webapp.htcpp.CTransition - Generated C:\Workspaces\PFC\aedifico-ui\sasdasdasd\connector_29_action.cpp...
15:29:55.750 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-26] DEBUG i.v.a.ui.worker.ConnectorGenerator - Transition generated at: C:\Workspaces\PFC\aedifico-ui\sasdasdasd/connector_29_action.cpp
```

All my workers do the same two things:

1. Generate a pair of C++ source and header files using
   Freemarker template engine.
2. Send messages to the `EDT` through
   the publish-process mechanism to
   inform the user how things are
   going.

I believe I've coded the `SwingWorker`s carefully. I was especially worried about the FileWriter instances not being closed as expected, but I can't see the reason the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is not reusing the threads it previously created.

The magic happens in the `ConnectorGenerator`. The `BaseWorker` extends `SwingWorker<V,T>` and just holds the behaviour to communicate to a component to display the messages to the user.

```
public class ConnectorGenerator<Void> extends BaseWorker<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        Transition transition = connector.getModel().getTransition();
        logger.debug("Building source code for transition: {}", transition.getName());    
        logger.debug("Project retrieved: {}", project.getName());
        try {
            publish("Generating transition (%s) source code at %s", transition.getName(), project.getBaseDir());
            /**
             * Transition.build(String), attached below, is responsible of generating and writing the files
             */
            transition.build(project.getBaseDir().getPath());
            publish("Transition generated.");
        } catch (BuilderException e) {
            logger.error("Error: {}", e);
            publish("There was an error that prevented generating %s's source code", transition.getName());
        }
        logger.debug("Transition generated at: {}/{}", project.getBaseDir(), transition.getSource());

        return null;
    }
}
```

And the `Transition.build(String)` method, including an ugly-as-hell try-catch-finally block:

```
@Override
public void build(String path) throws BuilderException {            
    generateFile(String.format("%s%s%s", path, File.separator, getHeader()), "action.h.ftl");
    generateFile(String.format("%s%s%s", path, File.separator, getSource()), "action.cpp.ftl");     
}

private void generateFile(String path, String templateName) throws BuilderException {
    FileWriter out = null;
    try {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("transition", this);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setClassForTemplateLoading(CTransition.class, "/");
        config.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.DEFAULT_WRAPPER);

        out = new FileWriter(path);
        freemarker.template.Template template = config.getTemplate(templateName);
        template.process(model, out, ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER);
        stdout.info("Generated {}...", path);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BuilderException(e);
    } catch (TemplateException e) {
        throw new BuilderException(e);
} finally {
        if (out != null)
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new BuilderException(e);
            }
}       
}
```

Does anyone see or knows something I'm probably missing?

Comment: I do not see in your code where you call ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @Romain, it gets called when you schedule the execution of the worker: ConnectorGenerator worker = new ConnectorGenerator(); worker.execute();

Comment: I didn't mention, SwingWorkers use a ThreadPoolExecutor with 10 threads, and it just create more threads if the 10 are running tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's interesting for you: [SwingWorker deadlocks due one thread in the swingworker-pool](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6880336)

Comment: I'll temporary fix it with my own ThreadPoolExecutor, I can't believe this is really happening. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a really annoying, that they didn't fix this in update 20